# Wrong cited reference numbering in a figure caption

Tags: captions, citing, includegraphics

I am preparing my thesis and there is a university latex template. In the thesis, I am using numbered citing for references with `/cite`. My problem is to start counting the references in the caption first. I don't know how to replace with appropriate number citation.

For example:

Bla bla bla bla [2] bla bla bla bla bla [3] bla bla

The figure comes

Figure 1.1 : Figure caption comes [1]

Note: I tried `\protect\cite{}` but it doesn't work. I am using packages of cite, enumerate, float, caption, graphics, and so on.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: First, please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Is it `unsrt`, `unsrtnat`, or some similar numeric style which does *not* sort bibliographic entries alphabetically? Second, do you have `\cite`-like commands in the arguments of table and figure `\caption`s? Third, does your document feature `\listoftables` and/or `\listoffigures` instructions? If the answer to all three questions is "yes", the simplest remedy would be to (a) cease having citation commands in captions and (b) recompile twice. Please also give an example of a `\caption` command that contains a `\cite` instruction.

Comment: I hope I can answer your questions with my limited infos about latex. First, my bst file says that my bibliography style file has been generated from merlin.mbs. Second, yes. My calling figure code is like that.   \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=14cm,keepaspectratio=true]{Types.png}
 \caption{Caption \cite{Albertson2005}}
 \label{fig:label}
\end{figure} Third, Yes i have listoffigures or tables. I cleaned auxiliary files, compile, build&view many more times on TeXstudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change

```
\caption{Caption \cite{Albertson2005}}
```

to

```
\caption[Caption]{Caption \cite{Albertson2005}}
```

and re-run LaTeX twice to fully update all citation call-outs.

Comment: That really works and solved my problem but I have faced the same problem again for subfig. When I use subfigure, your suggestion works for inside of \subfigure[]{} but does not work for \caption[]{}. Namely, works in Figure 3 (a) caption, not work in Figure 3 caption when subfigure is used. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Radioactive - I'm afraid you haven't provided enough information to allow making a diagnosis, let alone offering a cure. E.g., which packages do you load to affect the appearance of subfigures and of citation call-outs? Where do the `\cite` instructions occur? Please consider posting a *new" query, in which you would lay out all requied details about your document setup. That way, many more users will notice your query and be in a position to offer a diagnosis and cure.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much Mico for your quick reply and attention.