# Overleaf; My citations are numerical as they should be, but they are out of order

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

I'm working in Overleaf and using IEEEtran.bst and natbib. My citations are numerical as they should be, but they are out of order. They should be listed in the order they are cited in the document. I have tried just about all the answers I have read here and it seems to be a common problem.

Comment: How they are sorted depends on the code (the bibliographystyle) you use.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Hi Daniel, I've already replied to your Overleaf support request but just for future searchers: this problem is not specific to Overleaf and the most common cause is citations in captions, which are then printed in the list of tables and/or list of figures. To avoid this use the optional argument to the caption command as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425830/21344

Comment: This was indeed my problem. Thank you for the quick response.