# \listoffigures displaying the word Caption instead of the caption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I had a problem where references started numbering from the citations in figure captions. This was resolved by this answer [Wrong cited reference numbering in a figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425813/wrong-cited-reference-numbering-in-a-figure-caption/425830#425830?newreg=072ec46c4f0e4d749e87bbac1114d6d2)

When following the steps of this answer (replacing `caption` with `\caption[Caption]`), a new problem came up where in the list of figures, the figures are all named as "Caption" instead of the actual text of the caption. This was not the case before applying the above change.
Any help?

Comment: Please show what you have done by providing an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile.

Comment: The argument provided in the square brackets [] is what appears in the list of figures. The advice is not to put the word "Caption" there, but rather the version of the caption to appear in the list of figures. It should be `\caption[my short caption with no citations]{my longer caption with citations}`, where you replace the arguments with the appropriate text.